# Jquery post function not working

Tags: jquery

I have this jquery post that takes text from a textarea and inputs it into a mysql database and then changes a div value.  This is all done when a button is clicked.  The jquery function is:

```
 $('#editAnswerSubmit').click(function(e){  //the button 
    e.preventDefault();

        var edited_answer = $('#modalEditAnswer').val();

        $.post('../submiteditanswer.php' , {edited_answer: edited_answer , answer_id: answer_id} , function(response){

                answer.val(response);
                $('#editAnswerModal').modal('hide');
        });
});
```

I have `alert()`  all of the variables when the button was clicked and the correct values appeared so there must be something wrong with the post code itself.  I also had an `alert('test')` after the post but before the first response and it never appeared.

Contents of submiteditanswer.php:

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
$answerID=$_POST['answer_id'];
$sql=mysql_query("UPDATE answers SET time='2' WHERE id='$answerID'");
$edited_answer=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['edited_answer']);
$time=time();

$sql=mysql_query("UPDATE answers SET time='$time' , answer='$edited_answer' WHERE id='$answerID'");
echo $edited_answer;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chances are jQuery cannot find `submiteditanswer.php`

The path should be relative to `/`

Have a look in firebug, chrome developer console, or fiddler and i'm pretty sure there will be some 404 errors in there.

If you need help working out which path to use, let us all know where `submiteditanswer.php` sits in your directory structure.